# Как с onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView) организовать вызов другого API

Tags: java, android

В адаптере в onBindViewHolder я прописал onClick, с класса DataForecast.DataBean я должен взять id и с его помощью при клике на CardView вывожу дополнительную информацию.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ForecastViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DataForecast.DataBean searchModel = list.get(position);
    holder.timedate.setText(searchModel.getDate());
    holder.game.setText(searchModel.getCommand());
    holder.forecast.setText("Фора1 по очкам (-4.5) @ " + searchModel.getKf());

    holder.cv_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.about.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                holder.about.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.about.setText(""); //TODO здесь надо вставить даные которые должны быть загружены из другого интерфейса по id c DataForecast.DataBean
                holder.cv_forecast.setBackgroundResource(R.color.forecast_about_all);
            } else {
                holder.about.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.cv_forecast.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Как мне правильно организовать процедуру для получения данных и где лучше писать её?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Вам надо запустить сетевой запрос и по результатам обновить UI? Если так, то запускайте запрос, по приходу ответа изменяйте данные в адапетере, от коих рисуется UI и обновите адаптер/отдельный элемент списка вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Програма выводит список прогнозов, по нажатию на некоторый прогноз выводиться дополнительная информация которая берётся по другому адресу+id прогноза. Да, сетевые запросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. По клику стартуйте сетевой запрос
2. После его завершения обновите данные в списке данных адаптера
3. Обновите адаптер вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged();`

ПсевдоКод:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cv_forecast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            someApiClient.startRequestForIdWithListener(id, new RequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Data data) {
                    //update adapters data list
                    ...
                    //update adapter
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: someApiClient.startRequestForIdWithListener должен быть в адаптере?

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, ну да... Я же привёл псевдокод прямо в методе адаптера...